# How to resolve dependency errors in Maven with Nexus repository

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, build, nexus

I am a newbie with Maven/Nexus so hopefully these are simple questions i hope:

When i run mvn install on my project i get the following errors:

```
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.myproj.TestProj:jar:0.0.1
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 294, column 12
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin is missing. @ line 304, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
```

And the second error

```
[WARNING] The POM for oracle:ojdbc:jar:10.0.2.0 is missing, no dependency information available
```

For the first error i think wants me to add the version information to the following plugin

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

The question is how do i know which version to specify and where do i find out which versions are available?

The second error about the missing `oracle:ojdbc:jar:10.0.2.0` artifact is one i am not quite sure what to do about.  I have googled around and it seems that maybe i might have to download the driver manually and install it onto my repository locally. Is this correct?

I am using Nexus with Maven. How would i need to install the ojdbc driver onto the nexus repository?

I found this page from google - http://www.zparacha.com/include-externaljar-file-in-maven/
and it talks about about how to add the jar file to Maven. What i don't understand is what happens when i run the command described on that site to install the jar file? Will the jar file be installed on my local repository or the nexus repository?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: The messages are warnings, not errors. Your project builds and runs fine without serious problems.

The plugins and their versions can be found here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html

The Oracle JDBC driver can be added as can be seen here:
https://repository.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;quick~ojdbc

If the error still persists after using that artifact there is not much you can do about it - except for creating your own repository, but for those warnings it is not worth the effort.